# Working with ROIs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to calculate the average pixel value in a region of interest that I defined on a CT image. I used imfreehand to draw the ROI, but I do not know how to go ahead with the pixel values calculation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, could you mark it as accepted to help others find it please?

Answer (score 15):

How about this?

Make some data:

```
>> im = [rand(200,200),rand(200,200)*2];
```

Display it and select an ROI using `imfreehand`:

```
>> imagesc(im)
>> h = imfreehand;
```

[image: image1]

Make a mask from the ROI:

```
>> mask = createMask(h);
```

Just to show what's happened, make the region outside the ROI NaN, and display:

```
>> im(~mask) = NaN;
>> figure; imagesc(im)
```

[image: image2]

Calculate the mean of the pixels inside the ROI (which is bigger than 0.5, since I selected a region over to one side of the middle):

```
>> mean(im(mask))
ans =
      0.83782
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay, so masks are always binary? Cuz When I create a mask and display it, it automatically shows a binary image. How do I go about dealing with that?

Comment: Ohh I got it.. Makes sense! Though createMask did not work for me. I don't know if you wrote it as a function or just as a step for me to understand. I basically used the following code,
h=roipoly(i)
Once I created the ROI, I right clicked on it to convert it into a mask. 
imshow(h) will display the binary mask
av=mean(i(h))
Thanks again :)